# How can I convert the string values of a 2D array to integer values in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, integer

I've got a code like this:

```
a=[['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6']]

for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][i]=int(a[i][i])

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1, '2', '3'], ['4', 5, '6']]
```

It only converted the first value into an integer and left the rest as a string. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Note that this does not convert only the first value. It converts the values at ``[0][0]`` (``1``) and at ``[1][1]`` (``5``).

Answer (score 3):

You can `map` your sublists to `int` type within a list comprehension.

```
a = [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6']]

a_new = [list(map(int, i)) for i in a]

# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
a = [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6']]

a = [[int(v) for v in l] for l in a]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You only get the first element of each row converted to int because your for-loop is not correct.
You need a double-for-loop to get to all the elements of each **row and column** :

This should work :

```
a=[['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6']]

row_number= len(a)
column_number = len(a[0])

for i in range(row_number):
    for j in range(column_number):
        a[i][j]=int(a[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a numpy [array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6']]
output = np.array(a, dtype=np.int)
```

The numpy implementation will be more efficient than the one you attempted.